# Changes to inbound rules are not updating to instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

In the `AWS` management console I have a single instance. When I go to that instance's description and click `view inbound rules` I get:

```
80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0       ✔
22  tcp 24.47.137.69/32 ✔
443 tcp 0.0.0.0/0       ✔
```

If I go to that instance's security group -- only one -- and delete the port 443 rule, it get's deleted from the security group, but when I go back to the instances page and click `view inbound rules` again, I get the same thing:

```
80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0       ✔
22  tcp 24.47.137.69/32 ✔
443 tcp 0.0.0.0/0       ✔
```

Any idea why the instance's inbound rules aren't updating when it's security group's is?

Comment: Caching? What if you hit ctrl+F5? Or sign out and sign back in?

Comment: There's a save button at the bottom of the window.  You're clicking that after deleting the rule?  Also, instances can be members of up to 5 different security groups.  Is there more than one?

Comment: I have a similar problem but with ping. I created a rule to allow ping.  I test the ping and it works.  I then delete the ping rule, but the ping still works.  This doesn't seem correct.

There is one difference.  When I view inbound rules for the instance, the Ping rule does not display.  It also doesn't display in the Security Group. But the Ping still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the security group and then reassigning it to the instance did the job.

Comment: Why is this not a bug ?   Seems like a regression from previous releases of the AWS platform.

Comment: This is not a solution, it is a tedious workaround. The original problem persists.